# ValidateInput(false) not working

Tags: ckeditor

I have read all the similar question on SO already and none of the solutions seem to work for me.  I am submitting HTML (from CKEditor) to a controller

I have `[ValidateInput(false)]` on my Contoller and on my Action
I also have

```
<system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

in my web.config and the web.config for the Area my view is in.

However my HTML is still getting encoded.

Comment: web.congif? is it web.config? do u hav firebug or something like that, where u can see what post/get request goes to server? and what next request is sent  after that request.

Comment: sorry i just fixed that typo.   Interesting - just looked at firebug and it seems to have the textarea already encoded. So it maybe a CkEditor / Javascript issue

Comment: What do you mean that your HTML is getting encoded? The ValidateInput attribute has nothing to do with encoding. It's to disable request validation of some dangerous characters that is built-in ASP.NET.

Comment: When submit some html '<p>'  is comes to the server as '&lt;p&gt;' I thought it was MVC doing this. But as MLS pointed out it looks like the HTML is doing this on the browser nothing to do with .NET

Comment: @Daveo, yeah, nothing to do with ASP.NET. So maybe retag your question and modify it to reflect this?

Comment: you can use `Server.HTMLDecode` to decode it

Comment: @Paul that could not work. What happens if I really did want to show a < on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable.

I see the error when I declared my instance of CKeditor on of the options set was

```
htmlEncodeOutput: true,
```

- hangs head in shame *

No idea how that line got in there.  But without it everything works as expected